# How do i fetch Object ID of an NSObject though code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Can anyone tell me how I can fetch the `Object ID` of an `NSObject` though code? See the Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object ID is something meant for the IB to understand the difference between the objects.
There is no such API or a way available to fetch the Object ID of any component.

Answer (score 3):

The Object ID in Interface Builder is only an internal book-keeping value used by IB when deserializing/serializing XIB files, and does not exist when the Application runs.

You want to use tag, or alternately, a property/outlet.